How to create a global Vuetify Snackbar?
I use a Vuexy template 9.0.1 with Vue, that uses Vuetify, VueRouter, Pinia...
I want to create a globalSnackBar with the VSnackBar from vuetify, and put it on the App.vue and can call it from anywhere without import anything.
I tried multiple ways, but with, script setup I cannot go further away. I tried to install
vuetify-toast-snackbar, vue-my-toasts... but I can't use it or I do no how to use it for what I want.
I saw that some uses Vuex to create a store and thought maybe with pinia could make it, but I dont think so is the better way, altought create a plugin .
App.vue:
<script setup lang="ts">
import ScrollToTop from '@core/components/ScrollToTop.vue'
import initCore from '@core/initCore'
import { initConfigStore, useConfigStore } from '@core/stores/config'
import { hexToRgb } from '@layouts/utils'
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

const { global } = useTheme()

// ℹ️ Sync current theme with initial loader theme
initCore()
initConfigStore()

const configStore = useConfigStore()
</script>

<template>
  <VLocaleProvider :rtl="configStore.isAppRTL">
    <!-- ℹ️ This is required to set the background color of active nav link based on currently active global theme's primary -->
    <VApp :style="`--v-global-theme-primary: ${hexToRgb(global.current.value.colors.primary)}`">
      <RouterView />
      <ScrollToTop />
      <GlobalSnackbar/> 
    </VApp>
  </VLocaleProvider>
</template>

and use it like this
example.vue:
<script setup lang="ts">

// imports...
// code...

const refreshExample = () => {
  toast.text = 'Example refreshing'
  toast.show = true

// refresh things...
}
</script>

<template>
  <Table />
  <RefreshBtn @click="refreshExample" />
</template>


show all relevant code.  where is your snackbar code? where does toast variable come from?  is it part of your store?  where is the store code?  If toast is a piece of state in your store, then setting toast.show = true in one component can cause the global VSnackbar to display if snackbar has something like v-model="toast" where toast again comes from your store.

only are example of what I want to get but I dont know how to get it, I tried multiple ways but I do no if create a store only for that is the better way, there is no extra code, only example structure

We can only help you with actual code you've written.  You need some kind of global variable that a component can set and the snackbar can read.  A store is a good solution for that (use Pinia, not Vuex).  Create a store, and set a piece of state to control the snackbar.  If you have trouble, create a new question with the exact problem you're having.  Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service so you need to at least attempt the solution yourself first.
